# How to make Chrome Extension popup on the web

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have created extension,  I uploaded it on the chrome extensions, paid $5, now I want to make popup on my website, which asks user to add or cancel the extension. For example when user comes to my website, clicking somewhere, it automatically pops up and asking user to add or cancel the extension, so if there is any video tutorial, or something please let me know.

Comment: It's called [inline installation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation) and Google has pretty good documentation around it.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! save my day....